# Random function also gives out random amount of objects in Django

Tags: python, django-views

I am trying to make a function where I give random objects to my view, but when I try this it also gives me an random amount of objects even though I used the (k = (int))

view:

```
def homeview(request):
    pks = Album.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    random_pk = choices(pks, weights=None, cum_weights=None, k = 6)
    album = Album.objects.all().filter(pk__in=random_pk)

    return render(
        request,
        'home/home.html',
        {'albums': album},
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not answer this question better than the documentation did. So please read the green box "Performance considerations" in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in).

> Note the list() call around the Blog QuerySet to force execution of
> the first query. Without it, a nested query would be executed, because
> QuerySets are lazy.

```py
import random

def homeview(request):
    pks = Album.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    random_pk = random.choices(list(pks), weights=None, cum_weights=None, k = 6)  # pks to list
    album = Album.objects.filter(pk__in=random_pk)  # no .all()

    return render(
        request,
        'home/home.html',
        {'albums': album},
    )
```

Tell me if this did the trick for you. **For sure** it will give random results still if you do not have more `Album` objects than 6 in your database.